# Nombrar hoja Excel con formato de fecha especifico

Tags: excel, vba

me gustaría nombrar las hojas de `Excel` con un formato especifico *"nombre del día correspondiente a la fecha"* y *"fecha entrada por el usuario"*, me funciona bien el código excepto por la parte del nombre del día, siempre me muestra *"Sat"*, este es el código, gracias de ante mano.

```
Public Sub nameSheet()
  Dim strDate As String
Line1:
  strDate = InputBox("Insert date in format mm/dd/yy", "Text", Format(Now(), "mm/dd/yy"))
  If IsDate(strDate) Then
    strDate = Format(CDate(strDate), "mm.dd.yy")
  Else
    MsgBox "Invalid format"
    GoTo Line1
  End If
  ActiveSheet.Name = WeekdayName(Weekday(strDate), True, firstdayofweek) + " " + strDate
End Sub
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow en Español. Entra en el [recorrido](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para ver cómo funciona este sitio web. Si mi respuesta resuelve tu problema, por favor márcala como aceptada.

Answer (score 1):

> Las funciones relacionadas a fechas están determinados por la configuración regional.

El problema es al utilizar la función `Format`, utilizando la configuración regional Inglés (Estados Unidos):

```
Public Sub nameSheet()
  Dim strDate As String
Line1:
  strDate = InputBox("Insert date in format mm/dd/yy", "Text", Format(Now(), "mm/dd/yy"))
  Debug.Print strDate

  If Not IsDate(strDate) Then
    MsgBox "Invalid format"
    GoTo Line1
  End If

  Debug.Print Format(strDate, "dddd mm.dd.yy")
End Sub
```

**Resultado:**

> 03/05/17
> Sunday 03.05.17

Answer (score -2):

Has declarado la variable `firstdayofweek` que estás pasando como parámetro? Le has asignado valor?

Ese parámetro determina el primer día de la semana (en algunos países la semana empieza el domingo en vez del lunes).

Asegúrate de que ese parámetro contiene un valor correcto (consulta la [documentación](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/t8dc1aee(v=vs.90).aspx) de la función `WeekdayName` para ver cómo son los parámetros que pide). En la documentación se ve claramente que firstdayofweek es opcional, así que no hace falta pasar el tercer parámetro, así:

```
ActiveSheet.Name = WeekdayName(Weekday(strDate), True) + " " + strDate
```

Usándola así, `firstdayofweek` = 0 por defecto. Entonces coge el primer día de la semana de la configuración del sistema.

Si quieres especificar el primer día de la semana, el tercer parámetro tiene que tener el valor numérico del día de la semana deseado (domingo->1, lunes->2, etc.). Así:

```
ActiveSheet.Name = WeekdayName(Weekday(strDate), True, 2) + " " + strDate
```

Por supuesto, puedes pasar una variable con el valor numérico en vez de meterlo a piñón fijo.

---

Puede que devolviera siempre "Sat" porque, si ese parámetro es `null` (es decir, variable sin declarar o con valor `null`), alguna función usada internamente en `WeekdayName` podría estar devolviendo `-1` (a veces las funciones hacen eso para avisar de que algo ha salido mal). Si ese fuese el caso, talvez la función no está capturando ese error y sigue adelante con sus operaciones internas (lo cual, si Domingo == 0, podría ser interpretado como sábado).

Comment: No entiendo ese voto negativo... qué tiene de malo mi respuesta?

Comment: Vale, ya lo he visto... un "pequeño error" en el segundo ejemplo de código... lo corregiré inmediatamente.

Comment: No te equivoques al nombrar dicha "documentación" que pertenece a  `Visual Basic`. Los valores que tiene `FirstDayOfWeekValue` no son los que aplica para `VBA`, ¿Has intentado al menos hacer una prueba de eso?. Favor de revisar [Función WeekdayName VBA](http://www.excelfunctions.net/vba-weekdayname-function.html)

Comment: Sinceramente, no lo he puesto a prueba por mí mismo. Hace mucho que no uso Microsoft Office ya. Lamento el fallo por los ejemplos apresurados, y haberme equivocado de librería. De todos modos he tenido el mismo tipo de problema con funciones similares en PHP y Javascript (y he usado VBA en el pasado), así que confío en que mi punto de vista será de ayuda. Si quieres puedes editar mi respuesta incluyendo el enlace correcto, me parece lo más justo y razonable teniendo en cuenta que tú has hallado la librería correcta.